# Why doesn't Django generate references for foreign keys to models from other apps?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a Django app called `tickets`, with the following models:

```python
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

There is a foreign key to `auth.User`. However, when I generate the SQL using Django, it doesn't show a `REFERENCES` for `user_id`. Why not?

```sql
$ python manage.py sql tickets
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "tickets_project" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "tickets_ticket" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "summary" varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    "project_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "tickets_project" ("id"),
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL -- no references here!
)
;

COMMIT;
```

This doesn't happen when I invoke `python manage.py sql auth tickets` either, nor when the apps are in the same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't do that at create time, because if you're just printing the SQL for the tickets app, it can't guarantee that the auth tables have been created. So, it does them separately at the end - but `sql` doesn't print indexes, `sqlindexes` does.